# How do I make bash and it's apps automatically resize?

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I'm working in Debian, and I've noticed that when I resize my PuTTY window, the console inside isn't resizing to the new dimentions, so things like nano are running at 80xwhatever instead of the more useful 130xsomething that I've offered it.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Console apps can usually be told to forcibly refresh display: in most cases, it can be done by hitting `Ctrl-L`.  You might also want to check PuTTY's settings, to make sure that you don't have [remote terminal resizing disabled](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-features-resize) by default.

Comment: The "Remote terminal resizing" feature is for *server*-initiated resize (e.g. `printf "\e[8;%d;%dt" 40 50`). It doesn't affect what happens when the user resizes the window themself.

Answer (score 2):

Check your `shopt` settings

```
shopt -s checkwinsize
```